# Custom managed property is not coming in News WebPart filter option

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-news

I have created a managed property in my Hub site. The managed property is mapped to a crawled property which is coming from a site, associated with the hub. When I am trying to use the property in News WebPart to filter data, the managed property is not coming in the dropdown option.

I have tried to use the managed property in highlighted content WebPart to filter out data, but that is not showing in filter drop down options.

Could you please help me to find out what could be the reason for this issue?

Comment: When you configure News web part to show news from "This Site", then it won't show Managed Properties filter, instead, it shows "Page Property" filter.

Answer (score 1):

It is the expected behavior that Custom managed properties are not shown in the Property filter list.

See this document (Search for "*Property filter*"): [Configure a Content Search Web Part in SharePoint.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/configure-a-content-search-web-part-in-sharepoint-0dc16de1-dbe4-462b-babb-bf8338c36c9a) It does not talk about the modern News Web Part/Highlighted Content Web Part, but it does apply to the Web Part Filters.

It is recommended to use the OOB `RefinableString` properties instead.